# Arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

so i need to find a way to get my program to hold a string of names that the user is going to input. the array will hold a total of five names and is going to output all the information back to the user with their entered names. I am using a single main class. 
so far this is what i have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Names {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
     String [] name = new String [5];


     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String UserNames = input.nextLine();
         name[i] = UserNames;


       }
    }
}
```

I need to know if this is storing the names correctly in the array? I am very new to java and need some insight from the pros. Also if i want to get the names to repeat back to them will it look like this

```
{
System.out.println(" The names you entered are:" + UserNames );
}
```

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: It seems okay to me, but why not trying it out to see if it works?
You can also print them later by using a loop to iterate the array and print each name separately.

Comment: Local variables should start with lower case. Use `userName` instead of `UserNames`

Comment: Shouldn't you give it a shot and see if it works?

Comment: I also agree with Vertex, although this is more of a convention.

Comment: @NickL. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

"If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in all lowercase letters. **If it consists of more than one word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word.**" Emphasis mine.

Comment: On your same link: "Every programming language has its own set of rules and 'conventions' for the kinds of names that you're allowed to use..."
But I agree that it is a STRONG convention and that it should not be violated generally.

Comment: @NickL. And what I quoted is a rule, as within that section all conventions are explicitly specified as such and my quotation was not specified- Q.E.D, it is a rule. Not one that the compiler enforces, obviously, but it is a rule nevertheless.

Comment: My point was that it was typically a convention from the point of view that was not enforced by a compiler. It is a rule from the point of view that variables must be discrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're doing it right.

To print them, you need to loop through the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    System.out.println(name[i]);
}
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was missing.

Comment: @user2934105 Then you can show iajrz the answerer the courtesy of accepting the answer.  You might want to get in the habit of using the array's size to drive the loop.  Do that by using `i < name.length` in the for loop header.

Answer (score 8):

> i need to know if this is storing the names correctly in the array?

So, print the array once you've filled it with [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: This is the (more) correct answer. Don't write what has already been written.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by Kepani you can try Arrays.toString(arrayVarName)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     String [] arx = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "penta", "quad"};
     System.out.println(arx); // returns object hashcode and not the strings stored 
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arx));
}
```

in case you do not know whether you will be getting 5 inputs or more you can try arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("alpha");//Construct would be strList.add(input)
    strList.add("beta");
    strList.add("gamma");
    strList.add("penta");
    strList.add("quad");

    System.out.println(strList);
    System.out.println(strList.toString());
}
```

as you would realize due to the use of generics ArrayList.toString() return the complete list of strings store